# How to integrate AWS api gateway with EKS cluster to access the microservices deployed on cluster IP using ELB

Tags: aws-api-gateway, reverse-proxy, amazon-elb, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I have created EKS cluster in that cluster created 2 nodes & deployed few microservices on cluster IP.
As cluster IP is only internally accessible so wanted to configure it with AWS API gateway using ELB.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an ingress in kubernetes, it automatically creates a load balancer for the ingress.

If you are using route 53 as your dns manager then after you have created an ingress you can add an A record to point to the newly created Application Load Balancer.

Please refer to the AWS document here to create ingress controllers:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html

Answer (score 0):

One solution to the problem is to change the service to a Private NLB using the [load balancer controller](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html) and then link this nlb to api gateway via VPC link

Further process and documentation for the process can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/integrate-amazon-api-gateway-with-amazon-eks/#:%7E:text=Solution,a%20route%20for%20each%20application.)